# Default screen size for web applications

Tags: web-app, design, interface, dashboard

I am designing the web application which will be used by network engineers. This application will help them to know the statistics of their network.

I would like to know which is the minimum resolution to be considered while designing the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1280** is widely preferred resolution but **1366** is recently topping the chart.

More here: http://www.screenresolution.org/year-2016/

and here: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp

Comment: Interesting. I tend to use 1024 and 1440 as standard monitor sizes

Comment: Thanks for the links it was very help full as an appropriate rationale for stack holders :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to contact some network engineers and find out what screen sizes they are using. I imagine you'll get a wide range of answers but that a few of them will be more popular than others. Weed out the extremes and you should be able to use these results to find the (sensible) minimum screen size.

Comment: The product will be sold in multiple countries so I guess researching at that level will be a very hectic job.

Comment: @R.Rajpara: It doesn't have to be - find a forum, chat room or something and ask there. Create a web survey and email out the link... There are plenty of ways to ask a simple single question - we're talking about quantitative research rather than qualitative.